# handleOpenURL, what value is used for the second parameter (sourceApplication)?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm setting up Firebase in my app, and have no idea what to assign the parameter sourceApplication in a handleOpenURL function. I am trying to follow along with Google's Firebase UI Authentication setup.

I have tried inputting UIApplication but get the error "Cannot convert the value of type 'UIApplication.Type' to expected argument type 'String?'"

After, I tried inputting NSString, but for all things I've tried, I've gotten the error "**Can not convert the value of type 'Object.Type' to expected argument type 'String?**'"

```
FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!.handleOpenURL( actionCodeSettings.url!, sourceApplication: sourceApplication)
```

Comment: You should show us your code  that causes the error - and some helpful context, if needed. Otherwise it's hard to tell what causes the problems.

Comment: @Ezekeil Kim Would you please mind to respond to answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Its worth reading the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui). Please have a look before starting the development using `Firebase`. They have provided the sample code too.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL,  options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
     let sourceApplication = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String?
     if FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.handleOpen(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication) ?? false {
       return true
     }
     // other URL handling goes here.
     return false
}
```